# junit vintage vs junit jupiter. Тест junit vintage не проходит

Tags: java, junit

В чем разница между junit vintage vs junit jupiter?
При тестировании конструктора тест junit jupiter проходит, но с junit jupiter выкидывает исключение 'No tests found matching...'
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

столкнулся с похожей ситуацией когда в проекте пересел с JUnit 4 (Vintage) на JUnit 5 (Jupiter). Дело в том что у них разные аннотации:

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
org.junit.Test
```

и соответственно тест с новой аннотацией JUnit 4 "не видит", потому и "ругается" что никаких тестов не нашел.

Рекомендую не смешивать версии, а перейти полностью на JUnit 5 или остаться на JUnit 4 если по какой либо причине перейти невозможно.